# insert query error

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

My code mainly reads some data from a file and save it on mySql database. I used the insert sql query then used a select sql query to read all data in my database.

When running this code i get the error "Key cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: key} System.Exception {System.ArgumentNullException} "

how do i fix this?

private void bindGrid()//function to connect to database
        {

```
        string DocID = User.Identity.Name.ToString();

        string connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;"
                                  + "database=hospital;"
                                   + "uid=root;"
                                   + "pwd=missy3asoola;";

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader("D:/Senior/WebApplication-metbhdelaXD/WebApplication2/Textfile.txt");
            string sLine = "";
            ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();

            while (sLine != null)
            {
                sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
                if (sLine != null)
                    arrText.Add(sLine);
            }
            objReader.Close();

            MySqlCommand cmdread = new MySqlCommand();
            cmdread.Connection = conn;
            //Defining Mysql Parameters
            MySqlParameter Temperature, Pulserate, Timestamp, Doctor_idDoctor, Personal_PatientID;
            Temperature = new MySqlParameter();
            Pulserate = new MySqlParameter();
            Timestamp = new MySqlParameter();
            Doctor_idDoctor = new MySqlParameter();
            Personal_PatientID = new MySqlParameter();
            //Defining Types
            Temperature.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
            Pulserate.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
            Timestamp.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Timestamp;
            Doctor_idDoctor.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
            Personal_PatientID.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
            //Defining values
            Temperature.Value = arrText[0];
            Pulserate.Value = arrText[1];
            Timestamp.Value = arrText[2];
            Doctor_idDoctor.Value = arrText[3];
            Personal_PatientID.Value = arrText[4];

            //cmdread.Parameters.Clear();
            //Adding parameters
            cmdread.Parameters.Add(Temperature);
            cmdread.Parameters.Add(Pulserate);
            cmdread.Parameters.Add(Timestamp);
            cmdread.Parameters.Add(Doctor_idDoctor);
            cmdread.Parameters.Add(Personal_PatientID);
            cmdread.Connection = conn;
            cmdread.CommandText = "INSERT INTO medical(Temperature,`Pulse rate`,Timestamp,Doctor_idDoctor,Personal_PatientID)VALUES([@Temperature],[@`Pulse rate`],[@Timestamp],[@Doctor_idDoctor],[@Personal_PatientID]);";
            cmdread.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmdread.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmdread.Dispose();


            string sqlQuery1 = "Select * from medical where Doctor_idDoctor=" + DocID;

            MySqlCommand cmdmedical = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery1, conn);

            GridView1.DataSource = cmdmedical.ExecuteReader() ;  //ex reader for retrieving
            GridView1.DataBind();
            conn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.StackTrace);
        }



    }
```

Comment: can you ensure the column value for the Temperature is not empty in the Textfile.txt ?. Looks like the Temperature column value is passing as empty or null value.

Comment: This is the first line of my text file

37 68 2/25/1988 9:00 2 101

Answer (score 3):

You are not applying the values from the text file to your parameters. If you don't do this, and your column is a non-nullable column, then you will get an exception, and thats exactly what is happening here.

You should change it to be:

```
cmdread.Parameters.Add("@Temperature",MySqlDbType.Int32, 5).Value = //value from text file;
cmdread.Parameters.Add("@Pulse rate", MySqlDbType.Int32, 3).Value = //value from text file;
cmdread.Parameters.Add("@Timestamp", MySqlDbType.Timestamp, 15).Value = //value from text file;
cmdread.Parameters.Add("@Doctor_idDoctor", MySqlDbType.Int32, 3).Value = //value from text file;
cmdread.Parameters.Add("@Personal_PatientID", MySqlDbType.Int32, 3).Value = //value from text file;
```

---

Also, try not to use spaces in your Column names and parameter names. I would change `@Pulse rate` to `@PulseRate`

---

Furthermore I don't understand why you are giving the return value of `cmdread.ExecuteNonQuery()` as the DataSource to the GridView. This doesn't seem right.

Comment: I have to keep the space since this is the way it's written in the database.

I'm sorry but i cant understand, if im supposed to write the value of the text file in this.. then what's the use of reading from the text file ??

Comment: @Mino This depends on the format of your text file, so I can't help here. But you need to apply values to your parameters. Thats why you are getting the NULL exception. The SQL Command won't just magically interpret the values from your text file. You need to set them.

Comment: ok, so this is part of the data in my text file : 

37 68 2/25/1988 9:00   2 101


am i supposed to write 37 in my code for the Temperature??